# How do I use @react-native/typescript-config package if I already have a tsconfig.json?

Tags: typescript, react-native

To give an overview, the package `@react-native/typescript-config` provides an updated `tsconfig.json` template for working with Typescript in React Native projects.

> This package provides the default tsconfig.json used by newly built React Native apps.
>
> This template is customized for specific versions of React Native, and should be updated in sync with the rest of your app.

I saw in [React Native Upgrade Helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.73.1&to=0.73.2) page that this package is to be added when I need to upgrade my react-native package. But not sure how to use it if I already have an existing `tsconfig.json` file.

Any help is much appreciated!